# HELP: Stopping </table> ruin a HTML design

Tags: html

I have some BBCode-like code for my forum:

`[quote]` opens a `table`, `tr`, `td`...
`[/quote]` closes the `table`, `tr` and `td`...

But when the user writes another `[/quote]` it adds another `</td></tr></table>`, and this closes the table the 'forum body' was in.

I know there is probably a simple solution, but what do I put it in so closing a table will not 'break the layout' so to speak?

Div? Span?

Or is it more complex?

Comment: Shouldn't your server side code check for balanced `[quote]` blocks before converting them to HTML? I'd say that's a better solution than trying to hack your way out of it with CSS.

Comment: Using a different tag won't fix this, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try preg_replace/regex:

```
preg_replace('/\[quote\](.*)\[\/quote\]/', "<table><tr><td>$1</td></tr></table>", $string);
```

This would match up to the first end-quote tag.

Comment: How do I make it if they had multiple matched quotes in the thread?

Comment: This matches up to the *last* end-quote tag, because the `*` is greedy. This regex won't work correctly if there are multiple well-formed quotes in one post, it will treat them as one big quote with some extra tags in the middle. `(.*?)` is the un-greedy version, which will stop matching when the first close-quote is encountered.

Comment: So how would I do it for multiple well-formed quotes? un-greedy in a loop?

Comment: Just dropping in the "un-greedy" form to the pattern from paimoe's code should make it work as advertised. So the first argument would be `'/\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/'`. (That's assuming that, as paimoe assumed, you're using PHP.)

Answer (score 1):

It's more complex - there is no way to tell an HTML parser "ignore the spec between these two points" without telling it to treat the interior part as raw text ... which won't work because you are generating HTML from this BBCode.  You'll need to validate the user-entered BBCode to make sure it is "well formed".

If that simply *is not* an option, you can hack it by making sure that your forum body is only wrapped in tags that the BBCode to HTML generator does not generate - but that limits you quite a bit, and it doesn't guarantee that spurious close tags won't break your layout.